# How to throw an exception in PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.check_privs(
can_grant OUT NUMBER
)IS
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO can_grant
            FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS usp
            WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'CREATE DATABASE LINK';
         
           
           EXCEPTION
           WHEN can_grant = 0
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error');

    END;
```

How would I throw an exception in case can_grant is 0?
The exception part does not work.

Comment: What is your intention? Do you want to throw the exception or do you want to print the  message?

Comment: throw an exception and output a message. I want the flyway migration to fail and see my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be this one:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) INTO can_grant
   FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS usp
   WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'CREATE DATABASE LINK';
         
   IF can_grant = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error');
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Count is zero');
   END IF;
END;
```

Note, there could be other privileges (e.g. `CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK` or `DBA` ROLE) which would raise the error but permission to create a DB-Link is actually granted.